# SAS: Drop column in a if statement

Tags: sas

I have a dataset called `have` with one entry with multiple variables that look like this:

```
message reference time  qty  price 
x       101       35000 100  .
```

the above dataset changes every time in a loop where `message` can be ="A". If the `message`="X" then this means to remove 100 qty from the MASTER set where the `reference` number equals the `reference` number in the MASTER database. The `price`=. is because it is already in the MASTER database under `reference`=101. The MASTER database aggregates all the available orders at some price with quantity available. If in the next loop `message`="A" then the `have` dataset would look like this:

message reference time  qty  price 
    A       102   35010 150  500

then this mean to add a new `reference` number to the MASTER database. In other words, to `append` the line to the MASTER.

I have the following code in my loop to update the quantity in my MASTER database when there is a `message` X:

```
data b.master;
modify b.master have(where=(message="X")) updatemode=nomissingcheck;
by order_reference_number;
if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_SOK) then do;
replace;
end;
else if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_DSENMR) then do;
      output;
      _error_ = 0;
    end;
else if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_DSEMTR) then do;
      _error_ = 0;
end;
else if _iorc_ = %sysrc(_DSENOM) then do;
_error_ = 0;
end;
run;
```

I use the `replace` to update the quantity. But since my entry for `price`=. when `message` is X, the above code sets the `price`='.' where `reference`=101 in the MASTER  via the `replace` statement...which I don't want. Hence, I prefer to delete the price column is `message`=X in the `have` dataset. But I don't want to delete column price when `message`=A since I use this code

```
proc append base=MASTER data=have(where=(msg_type="A")) force;
run;
```

Hence, I have this code price to my `Modify` statement:

```
data have(drop=price_alt); 
set have; if message="X" then do; 
output;end; 
else do; /*I WANT TO MAKE NO CHANGE*/ 
end;run;
```

but it doesn't do what I want. If the message is not equal X then I don't want to drop the column. If it is equal X, I want to drop the column. How can I adapt the code above to make it work?

Comment: If you drop a column, it's gone for all rows of data. It's a change to the structure of the dataset. Are you sure you mean `column`?

Comment: Yes I meant column. I don't need the observations under that column if the message=X. I do so because it simplifies a future data step in my code.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate a bit in plain language what you're trying to do, it will make more sense when you say "I don't need the observations under that column...". Every row (observation) of a dataset has a tuple for each column. Based on `if` logic, you can set them to missing, not output them, send them to different datasets, or do something else. What do you want at the end, in plain language?

Comment: Agree @sasfrog I wasn't clear. I updated the problem but I believe I just figured out a much simpler solution to my problem. I should have thought about it before.

Comment: I agree with others here - dropping the column really isn't the right solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a bit of a strange request to be honest, such that it raises questions about whether what you're doing is the best way of doing it.  However, in the spirit of answering the question...

The answer by DomPazz gives the option of splitting the data into two possible sets, but if you want code down the line to always refer to a specific data set, this creates its own complications.

You also can't, in the one data step, tell SAS to output to the "same" data set where one instance has a column and one instance doesn't.  So what you'd like, therefor, is for the code itself to be dynamic, so that the data step that exists is either one that does drop the column, or one that does not drop the column, depending on whether message=x.  The answer to this, dynamic code, like many things in SAS, resolves to the creative use of macros.  And it looks something like this:

```
/* Just making your input data set */

data have;
message='x';
time=35000;
qty=1000;
price=10.05;
price_alt=10.6;
run;

/* Writing the macro */

%macro solution;
    %local id rc1 rc2;

    %let id=%sysfunc(open(work.have));
    %syscall set(id);
    %let rc1=%sysfunc(fetchobs(&id, 1));
    %let rc2=%sysfunc(close(&id));

%IF &message=x %THEN %DO;
    data have(drop=price_alt);
    set have;
    run;
%END;

%ELSE %DO;
    data have;
    set have;
    run;
%END;
%mend solution;

/* Running the macro */

%solution;
```

Comment: +1 "It's a bit of a strange request to be honest" but having a crack at it anyway for the OP :)

Comment: I have updated the problem above and thank you for your solution @DJM I believe I have a found a much simpler way to solve my problem but I will use your code for now. Thank you

Comment: @DJM I really like your code and works nicely. Thanks for the learning for this sort of Macro

Comment: Thanks :) Its not a particularly common macro technique, and you have to be careful of name clashes between the data set variables and the macro variables.  Don't rely on it needlessly, but its a nice arrow to have in one's quiver as it were.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
data outX(drop=price_alt) outNoX;
set have;
if message = "X" then
   output outX;
else
   output outNoX;
run;
```

As @sasfrog says in the comments, a table either has a column or it does not.  If you want to subset things where MESSAGE="X" then you can use something like this to create 2 data sets.

Comment: thanks I was thinking of doing the same but is it possible to have the same data set name and not two different ones like outX and OutNoX no matter if I drop the columns or not?